# Too many level of symbolic links while executing gcc

Tags: macos, plone

I'm trying to install Plone in my new Mac. I am having difficulties while running buildout:

```
Getting distribution for 'zope.security==3.7.4'.
unable to execute gcc-4.2: Too many levels of symbolic links
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
An error occured when trying to install zope.security 3.7.4. Look above this message for          any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
   Installing.
   Getting section instance.
   Initializing section instance.
   Installing recipe plone.recipe.zope2instance.
   Getting distribution for 'zope.security==3.7.4'.
Error: Couldn't install: zope.security 3.7.4
```

However python installation does say that there is gcc 4.2.1

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I don't know how to point `gcc` to right version or may be it different issue. Any help or pointer would be great.

I've got Mac OSX 10.7.5 and installed XCode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing command line tool.